# Weird Transparency when Rendering in Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, transparency

This is my first time rendering in Cycles since I just figured out how much nicer it looks with normal lighting, but I'm getting a weird transparency effect on the objects when the scene is rendered with cycles *specifically*. Here is what the render looks like in Eevee:

[image]

As you can see, all of the objects are fully opaque except for the wings, which is what should be happening. However, once this exact setup is run in Cycles, it comes out as this: [image: all objects are partially transparent]

Needless to say, I did not want my character to turn into a ghost. If this is a common error or if I just missed a step, please let me know!

Here is the .blend file if that helps (ignore the name): https://www.dropbox.com/s/4um4cgaxtm2wyn2/FloraRenderOverwatch.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've plugged some image textures into the alpha socket of your *Principled BSDF* nodes, in Eevee it doesn't create transparency by default as long as you haven't enabled *Alpha Blend*, but in Cycles it automatically creates transparency. What is your goal with this setup?

[image]

Alpha is useful for example if you want to use the alpha chanel of a picture in order to create transparency:

[image]

Comment: my goal was “only god knows”, because I have no idea how nodes work

Comment: ah ah ok, alpha is useful for example if you want to use the alpha chanel of a picture   ;)

Comment: fancy, i’ll keep that in mind, thanks